# JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of entity class

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-boot

i'v created a OneToMany relationship like this :

```
@Entity
//@JsonDeserialize(as = User.class)
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;    
    @Column(name = "roleName", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String roleName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "role", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();
}

@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long  id;
    @Column(name = "username", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String email;   
    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_role")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Role role;
}
```

and when i try to add a new user in JSON format with post method :

```
{
"username": "XXXX",
"email": "XXXX@gmail.com",
"password": "XXXX",
"firstName": "XXXX",
"lastName": "XXXX",
"role": 1
}
```

i get this error :

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-05-09T19:35:55.057+0000",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `org.vi.entities.Role` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.vi.entities.Role` (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 9] (through reference chain: org.vi.entities.User["role"])",
"path": "/users"
}
```

i'v already try to add `@JsonDeserialize(as = User.class)` to Role Class but it give me another error witch is `Content type 'application/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported` even if Content-Type exist already in the header.

please can you help me with this?

**PS:** i have the same relationship between another two classes (Category & Product) in the same project and it works perfectly, witch is weird.

Comment: The JSON text has a role id, not a role object. Either change the JSON to include full role object or change class you're parsing into to have a role id field/settermethod.

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly when i changed the JSON, but i want to know why it works when i just give the role id with GET method like this `http://localhost:8080/userss?username="www"&email="www@gmail.com"&password="www"&firstName="www"&lastName="www"&role=1`

Comment: That would be up to the controller code handing the `/userss` request.